# Linux: what is the most scalable design for making a system call like fadvise in a thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix, scalability, fread

My server has the following requirements:

1) each new connection to the server will trigger a series of N posix_fadvise calls.
2) the first few fadvise calls per connection should happen ASAP
3) ability to re-order the fadvise calls if the client makes a
subsequent requests.

I am thinking: thread pool with shared queue, where thread pool size is ~100. Any other suggestions?

Comment: are you doing anything else than those `fadvise`s? seems strange to have to do that many.

Comment: The fadvise is to pull a series of files from the NAS into the buffer cache, in order to have them in RAM; these files will then be sent over a socket back to the client.

Comment: I would just use `sendfile()` and let the kernel worry about managing its cache.  `fadvise()` is good when you actually _know_ ahead of time what data you need.  But for this application, it sounds like by the time you know what data you need, you are also ready to send it to the client.  So I suspect `fadvise()` will not help.

Comment: Thanks, Nemo. But, once I get the first connection, I *do* know ahead of time that the rest of the files will be needed.

Comment: Another point: the client is connecting on a 100 MBPS line, while the server to NAS connection is 1 GIG. So, while I am sending a chunk of data to the client, I can pre-fetch 10 chunks from the NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in having multiple threads blocking in `fadvise` at the same time for the same underlying device, since they're all sharing the same request queue anyway.

This means that you should only need a single readahead thread, that takes readahead requests from a queue and executes them sequentially.

Comment: you mention "the same underlying device". Are you referring to the disk, or to RAM. Because, in my case, I am reading from a NAS, so it may be beneficial to have multiple threads in this case.

Comment: @Jacko: The same filesystem backing device.  It would depend on how your particular NAS is presented to the OS - if you are worried, test it and see.

Comment: cool.  Thanks again, caf.  Will test, but it is good to understand theoretically what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED`:

`posix_fadvise` is already asynchronous.  That is, it fires off the kernel's machinery to start paging in data in the background, but it does not actually wait for any data to get read.  It returns immediately.

In other words, `posix_fadvise` is already a concurrency mechanism, so spawning your own threads to invoke it is non-sensical.  And there is no way to "re-order" the calls, because once they have been handed to the kernel, the kernel will make up its own mind about how to re-order the disk accesses.

If you really want to roll your own, just have your threads making blocking read() calls over and over to read small-ish blocks (like 8k).  (That is, read sequentially into the same 8k buffer repeatedly.  Using the same buffer will keep it in L1 cache and avoid hammering the memory bus needlessly.)  That will populate the page cache and give you some control over when it happens.

I am a little skeptical that your application needs such a mechanism, though...

Comment: Thanks, Nemo. Yes, the docs say that posix_fadvise is asynchronous. However, it is a bit more complicated than this:

Comment: "
They are asynchronous in that there is no guarantee the pages will be
in the page cache by the time they return. But at the same time, they
are not guaranteed to be non-blocking. That is, the work of doing the
readahead does not take place in a kernel thread. So if you try to
request I/O than will fit in the request queue, the system call will
block until some I/O is completed so that more I/O requested cam be
loaded onto the request queue.
"